# UILabel negative line spacing

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've got a UILabel and I want to make the line spacing less than 0 (so the text moves closer together rather than further away). What am I doing wrong?

```
    UIFont* customFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"BebasNeue" size:70];
    NSString * text = @"Their \nIdeas";

    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text];
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragrahStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    paragrahStyle.lineSpacing = -30;
    [attributedString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragrahStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, [text length])];

    UILabel *lbl1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    lbl1.frame = CGRectMake(120, 0, viewWidth, 300);
    lbl1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    lbl1.textColor = grayColor;
    lbl1.numberOfLines = 2;
    lbl1.attributedText = attributedString;
    lbl1.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    lbl1.font = customFont;
    [view addSubview:lbl1];
    [lbl1 setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.35)];
```

Comment: What does it look like with your code here?

Comment: You don't really need a label here, so what I would do in your place is make a custom UIView where I draw the text myself. That way, you can put the lines wherever you like.

Comment: @matt I was about to suggest the same thing. CoreText is probably the way to go here.

Comment: @Fogmeister No need for Core Text. Just draw two NSAttributedStrings in the place where you want them. Or, to be snazzier, use TextKit.

Comment: @matt ah, I meant TextKit :D Got the name mixed up :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please see the following documentation from Apple [setLineSpacing - NSMutableParagraphStyle](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSMutableParagraphStyle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableParagraphStyle/setLineSpacing%3a) , value must not be negative

> `setLineSpacing:`
>   Sets the distance in points added between lines within the paragraph to `aFloat`.
>
> ```
>  - (void)setLineSpacing:(CGFloat)aFloat
> ```
>
> **Discussion**
>
> This value must be nonnegative.

There are also methods related to the minimum and maximum height for lines… probably setting line space to 0 and modifying the height could help you to achieve the effect you want-

Comment: Well I've got a font that is so broken that I actually need negative line spacing but I can't get it…

Answer (score 24):

```
NSMutableAttributedString* attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:labelText];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
CGFloat minMaxLineHeight = (font.pointSize - font.ascender + font.capHeight);
NSNumber *offset = @(font.capHeight - font.ascender);
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, labelText.length);
[style setMinimumLineHeight:minMaxLineHeight];
[style setMaximumLineHeight:minMaxLineHeight];
if (isCentered) {
    [style setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
}
[attrString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName
                   value:style
                   range:range];
[attrString addAttribute:NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName
                   value:offset
                   range:range];
```

This should get you near zero spacing on the text and should be safe to use with any font type and size.

Comment: Lifesaver! Finally someone with the answer I wanted!

Comment: Can do even simpler: just set style setMaximumLineHeight to font.ascender and dont need to use NSBaselineOffset then

Comment: @NickKovalsky's comment to set max line height to the font.ascender WORKS and is much SIMPLER. Thanks!

Comment: @ericMurphey Can you take a look at this question/link and see if you can help? Appreciate it!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58069302/how-to-fix-uilabel-text-spacing

Answer (score 7):

Building off of [Eric Murphey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25537741/1176870), I've created an extension in Swift 4 syntax.

```
extension UILabel{    
    public func zeroLineSpace(){
        let s = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.text!)
        let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        let lineHeight = self.font.pointSize - self.font.ascender + self.font.capHeight
        let offset = self.font.capHeight - self.font.ascender
        let range = NSMakeRange(0, self.text!.count)
        style.maximumLineHeight = lineHeight
        style.minimumLineHeight = lineHeight
        style.alignment = self.textAlignment
        s.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle, value: style, range: range)
        s.addAttribute(.baselineOffset, value: offset, range: range)
        self.attributedText = s
    }
}
```

Simply call it like so

```
myUiLabel.zeroLineSpace()
```

Comment: Helped me a ton!  Thank you!

Comment: This works out great but with Xcode 11 and iOS 13 this doesn't seem to work anymore. I'm using this inside a collection view and when I scroll my labels text is not centered inside the label itself. Any help would be great!

Comment: Please don’t use force unwrapping and single letter symbol names.

Comment: This is perfect thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just a minor tweak to make things more configurable.

```
extension UILabel {
    public func setLineHeight(lineHeight: CGFloat, textAlignment: NSTextAlignment ) {
        guard let text = self.text else { return }
        let attributeString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
        let styleLineHeight = self.font.pointSize - self.font.ascender + self.font.capHeight + lineHeight
        let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            style.alignment = textAlignment
            style.maximumLineHeight = styleLineHeight
            style.minimumLineHeight = styleLineHeight
        let offset = self.font.capHeight - self.font.ascender + lineHeight * 0.5
        let range = NSMakeRange(0, text.count)
        attributeString.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle, value: style, range: range)
        attributeString.addAttribute(.baselineOffset, value: offset, range: range)
        self.attributedText = attributeString
    }
}
```

Comment: I was looking for that! Thanks 

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up Christ Stillwell's answer a little bit:

```
extension UILabel {
    public func zeroLineSpace() {
        guard let text = self.text else { return }
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
        let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        let lineHeight = self.font.pointSize - self.font.ascender + self.font.capHeight
        let offset = self.font.capHeight - self.font.ascender
        let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length)
        style.maximumLineHeight = lineHeight
        style.minimumLineHeight = lineHeight
        style.alignment = self.textAlignment
        attributedString.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle, value: style, range: range)
        attributedString.addAttribute(.baselineOffset, value: offset, range: range)
        self.attributedText = attributedString
    }
}
```

Comment: Great improvement for not using force unwrapping and single letter symbol names.